# Angular2+ : Refreshing of router outlet components data from outside router outlet components

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, router-outlet

```
<div><SearchProjects></SearchProjects></div>
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Whenever I change the search content depending on that I need to refresh data of router-outlet component data.

While first routing I am sharing the data using shared service, but it will not work because on init call only once. For next data for the same routing, it will not work.

I need to share data between constant search component to changing router(router-outlet) component. Some times for the same routing two different data need to be rendered.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Make the shared data in your service a Subject that can be subscribed to like an observable. When you use `subject.next(value)`, all observers will be updated. You would subscribe to the subject in your `onInit` function in your components that utilize the shared service.

Comment: Please can you share any example.

Comment: [I don't think I could think of a more perfect example than the one provided here.](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me try with my scenario. It may work for me.

Answer (score 0):

use service provider only at app.modules.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
   constructor(route:ActivatedRoute){
      route.params.subscribe(val=>{ 
       //    add to do function()
      })
   }
```

Need to inject "ActivatedRoute" and subscribe the params

Route only destroys and recreates the component when it navigates to a different route. when only route params or query params are updated but the route is the same, the component won't be destroyed and recreated.